# Ignore Duplicates in Count

Tags: crystal-reports, count

I have a report in Crystal that won't total correctly.

I have groups set up as show below:

- Date

  - Hour

    - Item

The actual data is:

- 8/20/2013

  - 9.00

    - 5411400
    - **5411468**
    - 5411497
  - 10.00

    - 5411600
    - 5411671
  - 14.00

    - **5411468**
    - 5443140
  - 15.00

    - **5441468**
  - 16.00

    - 5443714
    - 5443764
    - 5443813

What I need is a count of each of the 5xxxxxxx numbers for each group, but only counting duplicates once for the whole set. How is should appear is:

**Hour  -  Total**

09 ------ 3

10 ------ 2

14 ------ **1**

15 ------ **0**

16 ------ 3

Is this possible in Crystal? I've tried creating a formula, a running total (with and without a formula), and various summations (using distinct and non-distinct counts), but none of them produced the right result. It seems so far that I can only make Crystal calculate distinct counts per each subgroup containing the 54xxxxx numbers and not via the hour.

Comment: the formula you have used to calculate the disticnt counts, did you try pasting in report footer or header? did you check the summary fields> may be they have an option?

Comment: I tried the footer and the header just to see if there was a difference, but the header produces no results, and the footer gives me an incorrect total. Summary fields didn't seem to have an option for what I need to obtain either. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with below line as you said you want the count of 544xxx but here in 9th hour there is no 544****

```
What I need is a count of each of the 544xxxxx numbers for each group, but only counting duplicates once for the whole set. How is should appear is:
```

Tell what exactly you need. Will try to help

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I meant all the ones that start with 5xxxxxxx. I should have made it more generic.

Comment: Instead of filtering in report why don't you try checking option "Select Distinct Record" under datbase

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: In this particular report, there was a sub SQL query that was causing the duplicates. I changed the sub-query to not generate an "hour" for each entry but instead for each order.